# Angular 2- ngxDaterangepickerMd multilanguage

Tags: angular, date-range

In Angular 2 i have Date Range Picker with some custom labels. The code is

HTML

```
<input type="text" ngxDaterangepickerMd [locale]="pickerlang" [(ngModel)]="selected"
                      class="form-control" placeholder="{{'date-range' | translate}}" name="selected" [ranges]="ranges"
                      [showCustomRangeLabel]="true" [alwaysShowCalendars]="tr

ue" />
```

And the labels

TS

```
 this.ranges = {
      Hoy: [moment(), moment()],
      Ayer: [moment().subtract(1, "days"), moment().subtract(1, "days")],
      "Últimos 7 días": [moment().subtract(6, "days"), moment()],
      "Últimos 30 días": [moment().subtract(29, "days"), moment()],
      "Este mes": [moment().startOf("month"), moment().endOf("month")],
      "Mes pasado": [
        moment()
          .subtract(1, "month")
          .startOf("month"),
        moment()
          .subtract(1, "month")
          .endOf("month")
      ]
    };
```

I need to change labels programmatically depend of language of the page. I tried to use this.translate.instant('label') but doesn't work. So, what´s is the rigth way to translate elements of array using [ngx-translate](http://www.ngx-translate.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue and we solved it using this.translate.instant('label'). In your .ts file you need to subscribe to language change e.g.:

```js
this.languageSubscription = this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe(() => {
  this.ranges = this.populateDatePickerPredefinedRangeLabels();
});
```

And the method for populating the ranges should be like:

```js
populateDatePickerPredefinedRangeLabels() {
  let ranges = {};

  let today = this.translate.instant("GRAPH.TODAY");
  let yesterday = this.translate.instant("GRAPH.YESTERDAY");
  let last7Days = this.translate.instant("GRAPH.LAST_7_DAYS");
  let last30Days = this.translate.instant("GRAPH.LAST_30_DAYS");
  let thisMonth = this.translate.instant("GRAPH.THIS_MONTH");
  let lastMonth = this.translate.instant("GRAPH.LAST_MONTH");

  ranges[today] = [moment(), moment()];
  ranges[yesterday] = [
    moment().subtract(1, "days"),
    moment().subtract(1, "days"),
  ];
  ranges[last7Days] = [moment().subtract(6, "days"), moment()];
  ranges[last30Days] = [moment().subtract(29, "days"), moment()];
  ranges[thisMonth] = [moment().startOf("month"), moment().endOf("month")];
  ranges[lastMonth] = [
    moment().subtract(1, "month").startOf("month"),
    moment().subtract(1, "month").endOf("month"),
  ];

  return ranges;
}
```

When the language is changed "ranges will be populated with new values and the Date Range Picker will be refreshed.